# TransitionTo with context

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am having some issues with embers transitionTo, I can't get it to pass a parameter through to a state inside context.  Trying to use

```
test: Ember.Route.transitionTo('step', {step:1}),
```

But this doesn't pass the value of step in the context to the route.  If I had a state 'final' and used

```
test: Ember.Route.transitionTo('final'),
```

the route final is entered, as obviously no context is passed

Working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/reubenposthuma/6p6XJ/167/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for might be the `router.send()` method, which accepts a second argument as context.

so if you have this defined in your router

```
test: Ember.Route.transitionTo('final')
```

Then you should be able to call

```
App.router.send('test', {step:1})
```

from wherever you want in code. That `{step:1}` will then be passed as the context to the route.

Answer (score 2):

When using `Ember.Route.transitionTo('state')`, you are defining a handler, which calls router.transitionTo('state', context), where context is retrieved at runtime.

So `test: Ember.Route.transitionTo('step', {step:1})` is invalid, but context in the action helper, for example `{{action test controller.content}}`

see http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/6p6XJ/168/

Hope this helps

Comment: Oh, thats interesting that it doesn't work like that.  In the console I can run `App.get('router').transitionTo('step',{step:2})` and it switches to the correct state.  This doesn't work in the event I had setup (test in the jsfiddle demo) since App isn't defined yet.  I'm working on setting it up as you suggested though!  Thanks!